# What installs files here "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies"

Tags: c#, deployment, windows-services, .net-4.5, .net-framework-version

I am trying to deploy a windows service(development system windows 7, VS 2012, .Net Framework 4.5, C#) to a windows server 2012 R2 machine.

I am getting the following exception

```
"The type initializer for 'Bloomberg.MainProcessor' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'dcasdk.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found. "
```

I think is due to the references(System.Data, System.XML etc..) not being found in the path below, (this is from where the application refers the dlls in the development machine)

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5
```

I got **higher version already exists** message when tried installing 4.5 on the deployment machine.

I checked REGISTRY (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full`) based on some google discussions and found that it is already having 4.6.1 framework (`Dword 394271`) installed as part of the OS.

I also tried installing **windows server 2012 essentials SDK Installer** from below link, which dint create any files in the path "`C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5`"

```
https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/confirmation.aspx?id=34860&cffa64c5-a636-96fc-e97a-0e907fcc4c04=True
```

I have a couple of open questions now:

1. What i need to install for my 4.5 application to work? In other words what needs to be installed to get the files here:

   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5`
2. Why is the application not referring required assemblies form GAC. I can see these dlls in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319`

One more thing to note here: The same service deployed in local works fine.

I greatly appreciate any help regarding this.

---

Update :
I tried using dependency walker to check the dependencies of the application(Windows service exe). Below is the results. I got similar error with the dcasdk.dll as well. I am new to this tool. Trying to understand what this error means. Any help\information regarding this error will save my day.

I am still wondering how this works in development machine.

Dependency walker results..
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: This is a runtime error, it has nothing whatsoever to do with the targeting pack reference assemblies which are only ever used when you build your program.  It is simply a file-not-found error.  Not the first time dcasdk.dll has caused that problem, it appears to get shipped without two dependent DLLs that are needed to use this DLL in a .net program.  Contact the owner/vendor for support.

Comment: The two more dependent dlls are also added in the application folder. Which resolved the issue in Dev environment. This is only causing issue in the deployment machine.

Comment: @SSQs did you ever find a resolution?

Comment: Installing "Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 redistributable" resolved this error. dcasdk.dll had some dependencies with it.